# Microsoft Access isnumeric system language issue

Tags: vb6

We are having an issue with Microsoft access and a function called " isnumeric ". When running our software(it's using Access) on a English Windows, 12.2 is isnumeric = false , but on a Swedish Windows 12.2 isnumeric = true.

I am by no means a developer, I'm just trying to find out why this problem occur, since one of our developers is running into this issue right now.

Answer (score 6):

First of all: `IsNumeric()` is locale aware, keep that in mind when developing for an international market. E.g. `Debug.Print IsNumeric("$12.2")` returns `False` for me, whereas `Debug.Print IsNumeric("€12.2")` returns `True`.

That said, I can see two possibilities for this to happen: 1) the regional settings on the English Windows have been edited or 2) you're using a self-written `isnumber` method.

When you create a public method with the same name as an intrinsic method, your method takes precedence over VB's method. If you now want to use VB's method instead of your own, you need to prefix that with its namespace, which in the case of IsNumeric is VBA: `VBA.IsNumeric`.